# RHEL - NFS mounting failed

Tags: linux, rhel

I have an issue with nfs services in one of my client machines. Let me brief you my lab setup. We have a *server* and *16 client machines* connected in a network. We have **60 LDAP users** whose home is */home/users/username* in the server. So these 60 users can login from any of the 16 client machines and they will always be presented with the same desktop.

In one of the client machines, I am not able to login as any LDAP user. I am getting an error as "**your home directory is listed as /home/users/username but does not appear to exist. Do you want to use /root as your home directory instead?**"

I believe it has something to do with the nfs mounting services. I tried the below command.

```
service nfs restart
```

If I run the above command, I get "**shutting down NFS services**" failed. Is this the cause of the problem? How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it was not the nfs service. It was the autofs. I ran the command,

```
service autofs restart
```

And now I am able to login as a LDAP user into this machine.